# If wind rotates my fan, will it cause electrical problems?

Tags: motor, ac, fan

I'm planning on building a DIY dryer booster, using [this cheapo 220V inline fan](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/223187696565):

[image]

I plan to connect it to a temperature switch and a fuse, and connect it to the exhaust of my dryer. (I'm doing this because my dryer exhaust is around 6 meters long and the dryer is having a hard time pushing air that far.)

My question: Say that the air pressure from the dryer causes the blades of the fain to spin, before the fan has been turned on by the temperature switch. **Will this cause the fan to generate electricity and damage itself or anything else?**

Comment: No it will be fine. But are you sure the ductwork isn't blocked? I had a fan vent about that long and it worked just fine until lint collected in the duct and blocked it. They say it can help quite a bit to insulate the duct. Then there will not be condensation, and lint will not adhere to the wet sides of the duct.

Comment: that fan may clog with lint fairly quickly

Comment: @mkeith I do have a blockage problem, not caused by lint, and I'm planning a separate project to solve it :) A 3d-printed connector that's going to connect the drier to a nice 15cm hose instead of the 10cm I have now.

Comment: @jsotola I've got an extra lint filter (beyond the one that's part of the drier) before the fan.

Comment: My feeling is that you are probably going to find lots of problems with your system after you install it. But the answer to your original question is that, no, spinning the blades of the fan will not create any electrical problems. Good luck with your projects. Try not to burn down your house.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks! If you've got any pointers about things that could fail, I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: You could look at using a venturi effect booster (Similar to a dyson fan) rather than an inline fan to prevent potential fire problems.  Many dryers are hooked up with easy to use plastic flexible duct.  You could look at using a larger size if possible and using rigid duct for as much of the run as possible so the dryer doesn't have to work so hard in the first place.

Comment: Larger duct = slower linear airspeed, which COULD, ironically, cause greater deposition of lint. Same could apply to the oversize elbow proposed by OP. Objects suspended in a fluid stream tend to stay supsended when flow is fast, and deposit out when flow is slow. Changes in duct diameter cause air to speed up and slow down. It is hopeless to think that the lint screen will produce lint-free exhaust. There will always be lint in the exhaust.

Comment: If you have an electric dryer, and you live in a place where the winters are cold, you should consider direct venting of the dryer into the house. It will add warm moist air into the house, which can be nice in the winter. If you have a gas-fired dryer, then it must be vented outside.

Comment: Before you put your 3-D printed part in place, take a small sample of the same material, take it outside in a nice safe area, and light the sample piece on fire with a lighter or match or torch. Does it continue to burn after you remove the flame? Or does it self-extinguish when flame is removed? Also, does the plastic remain fairly solid at duct temperature? I guess you could measure the output air temp of the duct, then put the printed piece in a chamber at that temperature and see if it is still solid or if it is getting soft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite likely that the motor of your fan is an induction motor. Except if this kind of device is connected to a capacitor, it won't generate noticeable voltage even if something external makes it spin.

If this fan is a little more complicated and includes a rectifier and a DC brushless motor, there can be some voltage generated if the rotor spins, and the rotating magnets create some electromotive force in the windings. But, even in that case:

- the voltage will be blocked by the rectifier, and you won't see anything between the terminals;
- the electronics could be damaged only if the rotation speed exceeds the normal rated one, which I think is unlikely

As a conclusion, I don't think a rotation could directly damage your fan or external circuitry.

Maybe the highest hazard could come from the fan rotating (rapidly) in reverse when the circuit is switched on. In that particular case, the start torque and initial current could be a little higher than the normal ones.